# conio.h and linux problems

Tags: c++, c, linux

My program is compiling on Windows without problems. On windows i'm using `conio.h` on linux i'm using replacement [enter link description here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-conioh/). My first error: `typedef enum {FALSE=0x00, TRUE=0xff} BOOL;` and error:

```
types.h:39:15: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
types.h:39:15: error: expected ‘}’ before numeric constant
types.h:39:15: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
types.h:39:36: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
```

Comment: So what do you find in row 39 column 15 or 36?

Comment: this is this line : `typedef enum {FALSE=0x00, TRUE=0xff} BOOL;`

Comment: And column 15 and 36 are?

Comment: Which `types.h` are you using?

Comment: Nice one mod.. this was not a duplicate of that question, he already knows about linux_conioh project and linked to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is how to avoid re-defining TRUE/FALSE and BOOL.

When porting C applications, it's a good idea to have a header file which defines capabilities of the various systems you port to, keeping machine specific logic in one place.

Then in your source, you can work round doing something like :

```
#include "machine.h"

#if HAS_BOOL
    #define FALSE myFALSE
    #define TRUE  myTRUE
    #define BOOL  myBOOL
#endif

#ifndef HAS_32bit_LONG
    /* long is 64bit */
    ...
#endif
```

Then your types.h included after system files and machine.h, will avoid the attempted re-definintion.

In machine.h, you can figure out what machine you're compiling for (or set your own -D argument to C compiler), and set the appropriate capabilities, to enable code which works round things.  Whilst this may seem like overkill, when you're "just" doing one port, you'll find it makes things much easier if you port to OSX later.

It might seem fragile, but using this strategy, allowed usage of alternative signals packages, improved versions of malloc where needed, with minimal disturbance to the original version, so keeping one source base for all targets.

Answer (score 4):

The typedef clashes with some other header that #defines FALSE or TRUE.

Comment: When I'm compiling on widnows everything is okay

Comment: But you're not on windows, so you need to avoid defining TRUE & FALSE, I've submitted an answer that explains the traditional UNIX strategy (before autoconf tools) to port C programs.